# If a sequence of continuous functions converges to $f_*$ pointwisely and to $g_*$ in metric, then $f_* = g_*$?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, functional-analysis, metric-spaces

Let $C$ be the space of all continuous functions $f: \Omega \to \mathbb{R}$ from $\Omega \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ to $\mathbb{R}$ and $(C,d)$ be a metric space on $C$ with the metric $d:C \times C \to \mathbb{R}$.

Suppose that $\{f_j \in C\}_{j=1}^\infty$ be a sequence that converges to some function $f_*$ pointwisely (which is not necessarily in $C$) and at the same time converges to $g_* \in C$ in metric $d$, i.e., 
\begin{equation}
   \lim_{j \to \infty} d(f_j,g_*) = 0.
\end{equation}
Then, can we conclude that both types of convergence have the same limit point, i.e., $f_* = g_*$?

Here, the equivalence $f = g$ always means that they are equal pointwisely so that  $f_1(x) = f_2(x)$ for all $x \in \Omega$ (I assume the metric property "$d(f,g) = 0$ $\Longleftrightarrow$ $f = g$" is also defined up to this pointwise equivalence).

I know that if $\Omega$ is compact and $d$ is the uniform metric: 
\begin{equation}
   d(f,g) := \sup_{x \in \Omega} |f(x) - g(x)|,
\end{equation}
then the convergence $f_j \to g_*$ in metric $d$ actually means the uniform convergence, which implies the pointwise convergence $f_j \to g_*$, in which case $f_* = g_*$. I want to know whether this is true for a general metric $d$ on $C$  (and a possibly non-compact set $\Omega \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$).

If not, can you given a counter-example with a specific metric? Or, Can we say that $f_* = g_*$ at least in a.e. sense?

Comment: I am not sure if I understand you correctly, but in general it is not true that $f_*=g_*$. That's the reason why we have many types of convergence for functions in the first place.

Comment: You definitely cannot just have an arbitrary metric $d$.  Unless the $d$ is somehow recording the fact that the elements of $C$ are functions, there is no reason to think that there is a relationship between $d$ and pointwise convergence.

Comment: It doesn't hold for completely arbitrary metrics on $C$. The metric must be such that convergence in the metric implies pointwise convergence. But all metrics on $C$ one is actually interested in do have that property.

Comment: @DanielFischer Some don't. With $\Omega=[0,1]$, $f_n(x)=x^n$, $f_n\to 0$ in $\|\cdot\|_1$, but not pointwise.

Comment: What did you mean by this "I assume the metric property $d(f,g)=0$ iff ⟺ $f=g$ is also defined up to this pointwise equivalence"?

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen True. Next try, all metrics on $C$ one is actually interested in that aren't the restriction of a (natural) metric on a larger space?

Comment: @BigbearZzz That means in the property, the functional equality $f = g$ is defined in the pointwise sense. It can be also defined in a.e. sense, in which case the $L^2$ convergence and pointwise convergence possess the same limit point, i.e., $f_* = g_*$ a.e. (as discussed in http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/271202/can-a-sequence-of-functions-converge-to-different-functions-pointwise-and-on-ave).

Comment: @JaeYoungLee But the metric is defined on *continuous* functions only anyway ...

Comment: @JaeYoungLee That doesn't answer my question. I think you are confused about "equality" and "equivalent". Not that it really matter since you're talking about space of _continuous_ functions anyway. Let me rephrase my question: Do you also assume that $d(f,g)=0$ implies $f=g$?

Comment: @BigbearZzz Well, that is part of the definition of metric on $C$ (as long as the elements of $C$ are functions, not equivalence classes of functions)

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen While that is the first thing that came to my mind, the nature of OP's question make me wonder if I understood him correctly or not. I have a feeling that either the question is not well-defined or downright trivial.

Comment: @BigbearZzz You're right. a.e. and pointwise things do not matter since I considered the space of continuous functions. And, the property “$d(f,g) = 0$ iif $f = g$” is just the definition of a metric space with the usual functional equality $f = g$ iif "$f(x) = g(x)$ for all $x$" (But I think in the metric space with the $L1$ norm, it should be defined with $f = g$ identifying "$f(x) = g(x)$ for ALMOST ALL $x \in \Omega$").

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.

Let $\Omega=[0,1]$ and $d(f,g)=\int_0^1|f(x)-g(x)|\,\mathrm dx$. 
Let $f_n(x)=x^n$. Then pointwise $f_n\to f_*$ with 
$$f_*(x)=\begin{cases}1&x=1\\0&x\ne 1\end{cases} $$
(which is $\notin C$), whereas $f_n\to 0$ with respect to $d$.

Comment: This is the exact counter example of $f_* = g_*$ ($g_* = 0$), but $f_* = g_*$ almost everywhere. Then, can we say that $f_∗=g_*$ almost everywhere for the general case with any metric $d$?